# How to add addChangeListener for JSlider in NetBeans?

Tags: netbeans, jslider

I am working on NetBeans for a GUI based design. I want to use a JSlider and want to show the value from slider to a JLabel. For that I need to write addChangeListener for JSlider. But I am not able to insert any code inside the area generated by NetBeans. Can anybody please help me to get out of this problem?

Regards,
Abhishek

Answer (score 1):

You can choose the `Events` tab from the `Palette` which Netbeans makes available (Window -> IDE Tools -> Palette) and select the `stateChanged` event.

This should wire the component with the required method calls. All that you would then need to do would be to find the method which handles the event (created automatically) and fill in the method body.